# how to write notepad++ auto-complete plugin

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, notepad++

I'm trying to develop a small plugin that will do a sort-of auto-completion along with some other advanced features in order to create a primitive IDE to use with a custom scripting language we've developed.

So I want to know, how do the auto-complete plugins usually work? I have a basic plugin template that I'm playing around with (the C# one) and I see how the commands work, from a high level anyway, but I'm trying to figure out how I would create my auto-complete feature.

My first guess would be to make a command that spawned a new thread that retrieved the entire contents of the notepad++ text every 100 mills or so and then popped-up a little selector box or directly wrote the auto-complete possibilities when the correct pattern was matched on the newly typed text.

Any wisdom from those who have gone before me on this?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out. Apparently there is a "beNotified" method in my project template that I downloaded and it handles all events/notifications from the Scintilla/Notepad++ environment. I will probably be using the SCN_CHARADDED event to check the current line of text each time a character is added to the GUI.